# Summing the symmetric values in a matrix and writing it in a file

Tags: python, csv

I have for example the following matrix:
[image]

I want Python code to sum the symmetric values ("n1,n2" and "n2,n1" are symmetric, similarly n12,n1 and n1,n12 are symmetric)  of this matrix as shown in the above figure. Just to clarify I want for example the two values in the blue circles to be added together and inserted below this matrix in this same file or another file. Similarly the two red circled values should be added together and so on.
Please note that this is a CSV file.

```
import csv
source= csv.reader( open("E:/Work/Python Projects/files/combined.csv","w") )
for row in source:
```

I cannot make out what to do next. Please provide some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not really well defined, so you will get a rather generic answer. Numpy provides a lot of functionality for this kind of problem and the operations are vectorised, meaning it is fast in comparison to Python loops.

```
import numpy as np
#read csv file
a = np.genfromtxt("myfile.csv", delimiter = ",", skip_header = 1)
#e.g you have an array like 
#a = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
#sample input
#[[ 0  1  2  3]
# [ 4  5  6  7]
# [ 8  9 10 11]
# [12 13 14 15]]
mirror_sum = a.T + a
#sample output
#[[ 0  5 10 15]
# [ 5 10 15 20]
# [10 15 20 25]
# [15 20 25 30]]
#now flatten the upper triangle
all_sums = np.hstack(mirror_sum[i][:i] for i in range(mirror_sum.shape[0])) 
#sample output
#[ 5 10 15 15 20 25]
```

This obviously only works with an input of quadratic shape. You haven't specified, what should happen in any other case, so we don't have to consider this.
You also have to adapt [`np.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to your csv file, it provides many parameters to deal with different csv files. Again, the sparse information you provide make a more tailored answer impossible.

Comment: I still can't do it with your solution. My problem is easy to understand. Just want to add the values in symmetric cells. By symmetric I mean for example "the cell in row 1, column 12 is symmetric to the cell in row 12 column 1. Similarly the cell in row 6 column 4 is symmetric to the cell in row 4 column 6

Comment: Also I don't care where you save the solution. I just want a solution

Comment: mirror_sum = a.T + a

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,11) (11,12)

Comment: Your example above has a quadratic shape, hence the chosen script. What would be the "symmetric cell" in a rectangle 3 x 10? And did you check, that your file is read properly? I thought it should be 12 x 12. Did "skip_header = 1" remove the first row from your csv file? Then omit this part.

Comment: Got it. Thank u